# Static libraries in xcode c++

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I'm trying to include a static library ( .a file ) in my project. It's all been included correctly and if I include the header file within an objective-c class it all works correctly and I can call the functions within the library. As soon as I try to do the same thing within an objective-c++ class an error is produced -

> No matching function call to awt2_encode_file

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but do your class files have 'm' extension instead of 'mm'? Need to use 'mm' if you mix objC and c++.

Comment: The file within which I am trying to call my library function has the mm extension. The library is written in objective-c is this where the issue will be?